# How can you use rails fragment caching auto-expiry with query params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails has a convienent fragment caching method that allows you to specify the object and have the cache expire when the object is updated:

```
<% cache @thing do %>
   cached stuff
<% end %>
```

I'd like to include query params (I want to filter a list) and still get the auto-expiring key and can't find the way in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being very simple.

You can simply create an array of all objects you want in the cache key:

```
<% cache [@thing, params[:filter]] do %>
   cached stuff
<% end %>
```

It is also helpful to add:

```
config.action_controller.enable_fragment_cache_logging = true
```

to your development.rb configuration file see the keys and verify the fragment expires as you change the template.